# 12152 xhr response from jquery when wcf service is returning large data

Tags: wcf, response

I am having an application where its full dependent on wcf services , so...in one of my pages I am trying to bring a huge data from the wcf service , its arround 13000 characters of html .
but the problem is that I am getting an error because of the size of the data , I am having error code 504 of the jxr ( xmlhttprequest object in jquery ) ....can somoene tell me what to do what that ?

anyway this is exactly my case but I really want a solution else cutting the response
http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2010/09/01/ReadResponse_28002900_-failed_3A00_-The-server-did-not-return-a-response-for-this-request_2E00_.aspx

Comment: What status is that? The HTTP response status code or something else? And is WCF returning the page itself? Or returning some data which is used by the page?

Comment: yes...it's containing arround 80% of the page , which is 13000 letter , i tried googling arround and traced the wcf itself , it appears that there is some limit that wcf can handle on it's response...is there anyway to remove that limit ?? and that is the xmlhttprequest status , now it returns 504.

Comment: Can you post some code for what you're trying to do? I really can't understand what your problem is.

Comment: okay something like this for the service call function CallService() {
    $.ajax({
        type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: Url, // Location of the service
        data: Data, //Data sent to server
        contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
        dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
        processdata: ProcessData, //True or False
        success: function(msg) {//On Successfull service call
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
    });
}

Comment: and the service is returning an html ( it's a 9 images view ) so i am adding this html to the page...but I cant get it back because the response is big.

Comment: Please update the question, it's hard to read in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Okay , the answer to this was that I am using StatusDescription to pass my wcf result , and httpstatusdescription have a limit of 512 characters so I was exceeding that limit.